# Android: context.openFileOutput not reconized

Tags: android

```java
public void setUser(Context context, String userName, String passWord) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
        File userFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "userFile.bin");
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("userFile.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)) {

        };
    }
```

In the try block, openFileOutput is underlined red, though it is in my opinion used with the correct parameters. What´s wrong?

Comment: What are you doing with userFile?

Comment: Try to let it compile. Then look for the error message.

Comment: "openFileOutput is underlined red" -- hover your mouse over it, and it will tell you more specifics about what is wrong.